# How to I change ion-input's highlight thickness

Tags: javascript, css, angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

The ion-input elements on my Ionic App have different highlight (the underline) thickness/height for valid, invalid and untouched states like in the image below:
[image]

How do I change the thickness/height for ion-input elements to have them all uniform?

Comment: Just inspect into your form. Find the class of `<input>` and style for it

Comment: @Duannx That was the first thing I tried. ion-input has several other elements on top of it. not one of them has a border I can edit, thats why I asked the question here

Comment: Inside `ion-input` alway have an `input` element what have `text-input` class. Just style for it

Comment: @mikeaxle I'm trying to figure this out also. did you figure it out by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

use `--highlight-height: 0px; and --border-color: transparent!important;` in ion-item
and use border: 1px solid #000; in ion-input